# Password input field showing value

Tags: php, validation, passwords

I am working on a form so that a user can change his password. I have three password input fields, one for the old password and one for the new one.

I'm doing some server side validation on the inserted data and, if there is a problem, the page is reloaded precompiled with the values the user provided. When the page is reloaded the value of the passwords is present also in html of the page and this is a security concern.

Is there a way to reload the page, precompiling the fields but not showing the passwords value in the source code?

I know I could do the validations client side, so to avoid to recharge the page, but I would like to know if what I'm asking is possible.

Comment: You'd want to look into CURL for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible.

You could reload the page with an encrypted password, but that's a security problem on its own since a determined user will try to brute force the encryption.

You should not send the password out to the browser, period. Each time there's a postback, the password field should be cleared.

Answer (score 1):

No, not possible. If you want the password fields to be already filled in then the browser has to get the data somehow.